# A Small Web Server

Tags: webserver

Can someone suggest a small webserver implementation that will illustrate the concepts of what a webserver does?  It should be in a language that is easily read, and understood, and should implement security and cgi, maybe javascript?

Comment: Servers don't implement javascript, clients do.

Comment: And the servers that do run server side javascript usually use CGI (or ISAPI) to defer execution to something like CScript.

Answer (score 4):

[thttpd](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/), a tiny/turbo/throttling http server.

It is written in C. If by "a language that is easily read" you meant "not C," then nevermind.

Answer (score 1):

[lighttpd](http://www.lighttpd.net/)

Answer (score 1):

[Github Mongrel source repository](http://github.com/engineyard/mongrel/tree/master)

- Well documented
- Fully tested
- Mostly Ruby so it's quite easy to read
- You can pull down the repo and play around with the code quite easily

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rebol.org/cgi-bin/cgiwrap/rebol/view-script.r?script=webserver.r

A web server written in a few lines - easily understood.

or, this one, with CGI

http://www.rebol.org/view-script.r?script=webserv.r

What do you mean by security?
Javascript is normally just page content.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.rebol.net/cookbook/recipes/0057.html

one of the former REBOL ones with explanations

Answer (score 0):

The [Noir](http://webnoir.org/) web server (Clojure) is very neat, here's an example server:

```
(ns my-app
  (:use noir.core)
  (:require [noir.server :as server]))

(defpage "/welcome" []
    "Welcome to Noir!")

(server/start 8080)
```